# Dynamic radio button in DataTable in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating dynamic data table and assigning it to a gridview. I need to add a radio button to each row of the table. But I tried it and was unable to get it work.

```
if (dt == null)
{
    dt = new DataTable("Shedules");
    DataColumn c0 = new DataColumn("Radio", typeof(RadioButton));
    DataColumn c1 = new DataColumn("SID", typeof(System.Int32));
    DataColumn c2 = new DataColumn("FID", typeof(System.Int32));
    DataColumn c3 = new DataColumn("FROM", typeof(System.String));

    dt.Columns.Add(c0);
    dt.Columns.Add(c1);
    dt.Columns.Add(c2);
    dt.Columns.Add(c3);

    dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { c1 };
}


foreach (AgentPortal.SriLankanWebService.Shedule shedule in air1Response)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

    RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton();
    rb1.GroupName = "depart";
    rb1.ID = shedule.Sid.ToString();
    dr["Radio"] = rb1;

    dr["SID"] = (int)shedule.Sid;
    dr["FID"] = (int)shedule.Fid;
    dr["FROM"] = (String)shedule.FromLocation;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Your variables does not show enough meaning - what is air1Response? and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can put the radio button in the GridView itself - DataTable is meant to store data and not controls

Comment: air1Response is list of items I'm getting from a web service.

Comment: Can you just brief me how to add checkboxes into the gridview. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at the following link

http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/549.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Mhh Can't find the idea... Can give me a help

Answer (score 0):

Include the Radio button groups as RadioButtonList in your GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">  
<Columns>

   <asp:TemplateField>

      <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="scheduleList" DataTextField="ScheduleName"
          DataValueField="ScheduleID" />

      </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:BoundField DataField="SId" HeaderText="SID" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="FId" HeaderText="FID" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="FROMLocation" HeaderText="FROM" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In code beind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   GridView1.DataSource = air1Response; //bind your airResponse directly to GridView
   GridView1.DataBind();

 }

 protected void gvSchoolClasses_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    RadioButtonList scheduleList = (RadioButtonList) e.Row.FindControl("scheduleList");
    scheduleList = air1Response;
    scheduleList.DataBind();
 }
```

Read more on [GridView Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events.aspx)